# How to get Google contact images with Google contacts API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, google-contacts-api

Working with `Google contacts API` using `Node.js`

I am getting all the contacts except images by Google feed API

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/faizy04%40gmail.com/ya29.ZAFTNcQ6sEue40gFqH5h8h91k8LO8Bwvf50NUgQKKmsD5fipWg9XvN5GeHmyref_TK1xJZVrB9Ubuw`

For getting contacts I have passed the following scope with `passport.js`

`passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email','https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'] })`

everything is working fine.

Now I want to get all the images of related contacts.

Do I need to pass something else with parameter in scope variable Or Need to send another `GET`  request for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983484/google-api-getting-a-contacts-photo

Answer (score 1):

You need to send one authenticated `GET` request for each contact image that you want to retrieve. The contacts image endpoint is in the same authorization scope as the one used to get contacts.

For more information, refer to: [Retrieving a contact's photo](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo) in the API docs.